# Suppress hint about use of protected member

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

The [meta](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/meta) package provides a `@protected` annotation (besides others) to get analyzer hints or warnings about the use of protected members outside of direct subclasses.

> INFO: The member 'selectedChildrenChanged' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'MenuItem' ([bwu_ng_quick_nav] test/menu_item_test.dart:108)

I'm not interested in these hints in my unit tests.

How can I suppress such hints?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The suppression code for the `@protected` hint is `INVALID_USE_OF_PROTECTED_MEMBER`. Add a suppression comment like:

```
  // ignore: INVALID_USE_OF_PROTECTED_MEMBER
  app.quickNav.keyDownHandler(ctrlKeyDown);
```

or

```
   // ignore_for_file: INVALID_USE_OF_PROTECTED_MEMBER
```

The codes for other hints can be found in

- https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages

or in the source code

- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/pkg/analyzer/lib/src/dart/error/syntactic_errors.g.dart
- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/pkg/analyzer/lib/src/dart/error/hint_codes.g.dart
- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/pkg/analyzer/lib/src/dart/error/ffi_code.g.dart
- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/pkg/analyzer/lib/src/dart/error/todo_codes.dart#L14-L17

This works with `Dart VM version: 1.16.0-edge`. I don't know with what version this was released.

Hopefully these IDs will be part of the warnings soon to not have to look them up.

Comment: Updated link to the hint codes: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/pkg/analyzer/lib/src/error/codes.dart

Comment: Please update your links, they contain only imports now. Thank you.

Comment: [Newly updated link](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/74fb9e190fa1ff7c5cf1334488bd46dcc91d09bd/pkg/analyzer/lib/src/error/error_code_values.g.dart) to hints and error codes: