# How to handle implicit cast warnings of strong mode analysis?

Tags: dart

A common thing I do in my web application is request a resource from the server and handle it as a Map in dart.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

const String sampleJSON = '''
{
    "member": {
        "meaningOfLife": 42
    }
}
''';

Map<String, dynamic> getResource() {
  // do some magic
  return JSON.decode(sampleJSON);
}
```

I live with the assumption that all keys in a JSON decoded Map will be Strings but obviously I have no clue of the value's type. In checked mode this worked fairly well.

Analysis in strong mode to the code above will tell me: `Unsound implicit cast from dynamic to Map<String, dynamic>`

## Question:

What is a good strategy to handle such cast warnings?

### Questionable options 1:

```dart
Map getResource() {
  // do some magic
  return JSON.decode(sampleJSON);
}
```

Later this could be a problem: `Iterable<String> keys = getResource().keys` will give a warning.

### Questionable option 2:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> getResource() {
  // do some magic
  return new Map<String, dynamic>.from(JSON.decode(sampleJSON));
}
```

Does it not degrade performance much? And I will still get a warning for `Map<String, dynamic> meaning = getResource()["member"];`

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the type then just make it explicit

```
return JSON.decode(sampleJSON) as Map<String,dynamic>;
```

The Flutter team forbids the use of `as` because it introduces a runtime check and has performance implications. If it is relevant, depends on your requirements.

Alternatively, you can just silence the warning (might not yet work in your Dart version)

```
// ignore: STRONG_MODE_DOWN_CAST_COMPOSITE
return JSON.decode(sampleJSON);
```

See also [Suppress hint about use of protected member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969619/suppress-hint-about-use-of-protected-member)