# How to set up strong-mode Dart Analyzer in Webstorm?

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

In my Dart yaml file I have

```
analyzer:
  strong-mode: true
```

but it doesn't do anything.  I also added the analyzer:

```
dependencies:
   analyzer: any
   browser: ^0.10.0
   polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.16
   polymer_elements: ^1.0.0-rc.8
```

I'm missing something (brain I reckon). What is it please?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a file `analysis_options.yaml` (<strike>`.analysis_options`</strike> old) in the directory where your `pubspec.yaml` is.

add

```yml
analyzer:
  strong-mode: true
```

or if you also want to disable implicit-casts and/or implicit-dynamic

```yml
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
    implicit-dynamic: false
```

You can also enable additional linter rules

```yml
linter:
  rules:
    - always_declare_return_types
```

For all supported linter rules see http://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/ and [Suppress hint about use of protected member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969619/suppress-hint-about-use-of-protected-member)

See also https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/analysis-options

Comment: this has changed to `analysis_options.yaml`

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert You're right. Thanks a lot - fixed.