# Ignore certain inspections

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

There are some cases where inspections are rather annoying and even mention that the file has errors.

Using `// ignore: argument_type_not_assignable` does supress the error message. Although I use this quite often, so it is annoying to have this comment spread accross the code base.

In the `Settings > Inspections` couldn't find anything neither under `Dart` nor `General`.

Is there a way to supress specific inspections?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here, because the argument to `then` is completely wrong and it will not work. In Dart 2, it will be a compile-time error, and no amount of ignoring warnings will make it compile. It might currently run when compiled to JavaScript with no checking, but that's really an accident of compilation, and not something I recommend that you rely on. Just write `.then((_) => print('finished'))`.

Comment: Yeah, only noticed that after I asked, I'll update the question. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure that using the `analysis_options.yaml` file

https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/analysis-options

```
analyzer:
  errors:
    argument_type_not_assignable: ignore
```

See also [Suppress hint about use of protected member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969619/suppress-hint-about-use-of-protected-member/35969635#35969635)